# Why that method work so slow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I have wrote an Windows Forms C# application for drawing vector primitives such like lines. ellipses etc. I have a method for changing border width of a selected figure. This is the method:

```
   public void SetBorderWidth(int border)
    {
        if (border < 0) 
            return;

        if ((SelectedItem != null) && (SelectedItem.isGroup == false)) 
        {              
            SelectedItem.BorderWidth = border;
        }

        if ((SelectedItem != null) && (SelectedItem.isGroup == true))
        {

            ChangeCascadeBorderWidth(SelectedItem, border);
        }

        foreach (Shape figure in ObjectsDrawn)
        {
            if (figure.Selected)
            {
                ObjectsDrawn[ObjectsDrawn.IndexOf(figure)].BorderWidth = border;
            }

            if (figure.isGroup)
            {
                ChangeCascadeBorderWidth(figure, border);
            }
        }            
    }
```

who calls the method:

```
    private void ChangeCascadeBorderWidth(Shape group, int width)
    {
        foreach (Shape item in ((Grouping)group).GroupedElements)
        {
            if (item.isGroup == true)
            {
                ChangeCascadeBorderWidth(item, width);
            }
            else
            {
                item.BorderWidth = width;
            }
        }
    }
```

if the figure is group of several figures. But this works too slow. No matter if I have chosen one or group of figures, sometimes I have to wait 10-15 sec. for changing border width. Why is so slow?

Comment: Pause the debugger multiple times. Where does it stop the most?

Comment: When I have one figure it stops one time here: SelectedItem.BorderWidth = border; and one time here: ObjectsDrawn[ObjectsDrawn.IndexOf(figure)].BorderWidth = border;.

When I have a group of two figures it stops one time here: ChangeCascadeBorderWidth(SelectedItem, border);, one time here: ChangeCascadeBorderWidth(figure, border);, one time here: ObjectsDrawn[ObjectsDrawn.IndexOf(figure)].BorderWidth = border; and four times here: item.BorderWidth = width;.

Comment: Now you know which lines are slow! Find out why. Look at the call stack to see in which function the thread was stopped. My guess: IndexOf on a long list.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

A width of one pixel results in faster performance since a border may be rendered using line-based primitives.

When you are using a width greater than 1, it must use solid-filled primitives which will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is editing the border of the SelectedItem, any ObjectDrawn that has Selected property set to true, and the border all all objects drawn that belong to a group.

Did you mean to filter your group border drawing also based on whether the group shape is selected?
`figure.isGroup && figure.Selected`
Otherwise, it seems it would modify the border of all groups, which if there are many, could cause the performance problems regardless of what you have selected.

Additional performance improvement suggestions: 
You do this in SetBorderWidth: 
    `ObjectsDrawn[ObjectsDrawn.IndexOf(figure)].BorderWidth = border;` 
But you do this in ChangeCascadeBorderWidth:
    `item.BorderWidth = width;`
I suggest doing the same thing in the SetBorderWidth function sice you already have the instance of the object you wish to modify, the IndexOf lookup does not appear to be necessary.

Also, if the cost of setting the BorderWidth property is high (even if setting to the same existing value), then wrapping your call to SetBorderWidth like this:
`if(item.BorderWidth != width) item.BorderWidth = width;` could save on performance.  But you have to evaluate the cost of the comparison against the cost of setting the border width.

Answer (score 0):

All the bottlenecks you posted seem to be from setting the BorderWidth property on your shapes. I'm guessing you do repainting or updating the layout of the shapes in BorderWidth. If you set BorderWidth on a container there will a lot of unnecessary repaints and layout changes which are kind of slow in WinForms (specially for layouts, if your shapes inherit from Control).

Might I suggest a *BeginUpdate* *EndUpdate* mechanism like some other WinForms controls?